# How to create a spark dataframe after reading data directly from kafka queue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

the data from kafka queue would be a line delimited json string like below

{"header":{"platform":"atm","msgtype":"1","version":"1.0"},"details":[{"bcc":"5814","dsrc":"A","aid":"5678"},{"bcc":"5814","dsrc":"A","mid":"0003"},{"bcc":"5812","dsrc":"A","mid":"0006"}]}

{"header":{"platform":"atm","msgtype":"1","version":"1.0"},"details":[{"bcc":"5814","dsrc":"A","aid":"1234"},{"bcc":"5814","dsrc":"A","mid":"0004"},{"bcc":"5812","dsrc":"A","mid":"0009"}]}

{"header":{"platform":"atm","msgtype":"1","version":"1.0"},"details":[{"bcc":"5814","dsrc":"A","aid":"1234"},{"bcc":"5814","dsrc":"A","mid":"0004"},{"bcc":"5812","dsrc":"A","mid":"0009"}]}

how can we create a dataframe in python for the above input? I have many columns to access the above is only a sample, the data would have 23 columns in total.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [pyspark.sql.SQLContext.jsonRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.jsonRDD). Since Spark streaming is batched, your stream object will return a series of RDDs, each of which can be made into a DF via `jsonRDD`.

Comment: @ Pedro Silva thanks ! i am trying to run the below code but am getting error                                                                                                         sc = SparkContext()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.jsonRDD("/nro0/app/spark/examples/src/main/resources/input.json")
df.show()                                                                                                         AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mapPartitions'

Comment: `jsonRDD` expects an `RDD`. If you want to read a file, you need `sqlContext.read.json`.